# How do I return the sum of two perfect numbers in C

Tags: c, perfect-numbers

I have a method named `henry` that takes two integer arguments, `i` and `j`, and returns the sum of the `ith` and `jth` perfect numbers. For example, `henry(1, 3)` should return `502` because `6` is the `1st perfect number` and `496` is the `3rd perfect number` and `6 + 496 = 502.`

```
int henry (int i, int j)
 {
      //how do i start 
 }
```

I know how to print perfect number like this:

```
int main()  
{  
    int i, j, n, sum = 0;  

    /* Reads upper limit to print perfect numbers upto */  
    printf("Enter any number to print perfect number up to: ");  
    scanf("%d", &n);  



    printf("\nAll Perfect numbers between 1 to %d:\n", n);  


    /* 
     * Iterates from 1 to n and print if it is perfect number 
     */  
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)  
    {  
        sum = 0;  

        /* 
         * Checks whether the current number i is Perfect number or not 
         */  
        for(j=1; j<i; j++)  
        {  
            if(i%j==0)  
            {  
                sum += j;  
            }  
        }  

        /* If the current number i is Perfect number */  
        if(sum == i)  
        {  
            printf("%d is Perfect Number\n", i);  
        }  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

Please give me hint to solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: The algorithm you have used here is very slow, and I think you won't find more than 4 (6, 28, 496, 8128)

Comment: Start by changing the `i` and `j` arguments for `henry` to something else, such as `a` and `b` that do not conflict with the `i` and `j` used in your perfect sum testing that will have to implemented in `henry`. It might then be clearer how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int henry(int i,int j)
{
int count=0,k=1,s=0;
  while(count<=i || count<=j)
  {
   int sum=0;
   for(p=1; p<=k/2; p++)  
    {  
        if(k%p==0)  
        {  
            sum += p;  
        }  
    }
   if(sum==k)
   count++;
   if(count==i||count==j)
   s+=k;
   k++;
  }
if(i!=j)
return s;
else
return 2*s;
}
```

Comment: if `i == j` your function returns `ith perfect_number` instead of `2* ith perfect_number`

Comment: ..and: you must `k++` after incrementing `s`

Comment: Could use more clear formatting (and overflow detection) - other than that, nice answer.